# UIWebView content width?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` in a Cocoa Touch app that may be different widths depending on device, sidebar (really, the master view of a split view controller) and orientation.

How can I set the content to always be the width of the view?

I've tried setting the width of the viewport to `device-width`. This works perfectly on the iPhone, but on the iPad doesn't take the sidebar into consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that setting `initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0` for the viewport, and leaving `device-width` unset, gives me the effect I want.  Might not be exactly what you want.

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I wanted. Thank you.